# Security threats with private server hosting

Tags: security, ftp, hosting, ip-address

Ok, been hosting a few games servers on my home computer, and am now also setting up a personal ftp server.

I am sharing my ip-adress with some friends and family with intetions of using this server, but when one of my friends threatened "hacking" my computer (I know he doesn't possess any such skills). It got me thinking.

If I do not reveal my ip address to strangers (or even if I do), are there any security threats.

Also at what scale are these threats. Will an every day programmer be able to cause damage while I host this server?

P.S. I am using `xlight` ftp software to host this server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your friends are not the ones you have to concern about.

Your ip , like everyone else, will be scanned in several ports several times per minute.

Internet is full of bots, launching petitions, looking for holes to exploit and systems to
dig in.

Just be sure to be behind a firewall, `nat` only desired services ports, and try not to use a conventional one. Install an additional software firewall if possible.

I would also recommend you to use a `SFTP server`. (Based on SSH and encryped). Standard FTP traffic is raw and can be easily sniffed.

Comment: Thnx, any recommendations for software I should use?

Comment: Also, anyway to somewhat ensure protection?

Comment: Being behind a router, installing software firewall and using SFTP server. If you are using Windows try this for example: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/tr-dojo/set-up-a-free-ssh-server-on-windows-7-with-freesshd/

Comment: And just wondering, is there a way I can still use `xlight` while ensuring security. I've already looked at some firewall programs, and have a security software installed on my computer, but what else can I do?

Comment: of course you can still use xlight. Just install software firewall and monitor traffic log every day to ensure your system is not in jeopardy.

Comment: Also be sure to configure service in different port numbers

Comment: Wow, so thats all I can do to protect my self from hackers? Is the system already that safe, or is there nothing else I can do. I mean, I only host the server on the week-end for exactly 2 hours, and I'm on the computer when its on. Is that good enough?

Comment: Remembers no one is safe for hackers, not even big companies. Be sure aswell of installing of windows security updates to avoid hackers to use exploits on your system